# How do I start the mission on Dathomir in Empire at War: Forces of Corruption?

Tags: star-wars-empire-at-war

If I try to move any unit on Dathomir, Zann says it's a mission for Uthar and him alone. However, when I try to move them there nothing happens (including dialog).

Answer (score 3):

Beginning the mission is a three step process:

1. Send a defiler to corrupt Dathomir (use any method of corruption you prefer).
2. After Dathomir is corrupted, send a defiler to sabotage the orbital scanner.
3. Move Zann and Urai as a two person fleet to Dathomir.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Destroy the Orbitalscanner first....then you can move zan and urai to the planet

Comment: You need to *sabotage* the orbital scanner with a *defiler* first.